# No cloud-to-device message received on a module

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I had created a module to receive cloud to device message, but no message was received on the module, is there any coding I missing?

```
var Transport = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;
var Client = require('azure-iot-device').ModuleClient;

Client.fromEnvironment(Transport, function (err, client) {
 if (err) {
   throw err;
 } else {
    client.on('error', function (err) {
      throw err;
    });

    // connect to the Edge instance
    client.open(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        console.log('IoT Hub module client initialized');

        client.on('message', function (msg) {
          client.complete(msg, printResultFor('Receiving message'));
          var message = msg.getBytes().toString('utf8');  
          console.log('----');
          console.log(message);
          console.log('----');
          var outputMsg = new Message(message);
          client.sendOutputEvent('output1', outputMsg,     printResultFor('Sending received message'));
        });

        client.on('error', function (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        });

        console.log('now listening for C2D messages...');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**Monitor**

> [C2DMessageMonitor] Message Received: "[{\"machine\":{\"temperature\":40.750164436176497,\"pressure\":1.0854617712099808},\"ambient\":{\"temperature\":40.450729128416036,\"humidity\":26},\"timeCreated\":\"2018-08-06T13:28:52.0375008Z\"}]"
>
> [C2DMessageMonitor] Status: MessageCompleted

Answer (score 1):

C2D messages are not yet officially supported by IoT edge. It may work for some protocols as the support is being built out but nothing has been validated at this time.